# Is there a function to find average age?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

How do i find average in js,
lets say:

```
var student:[
{name:"mia", age: 20},
{name:"kia", age: 25},
{name:"dia", age: 23}
];
```

Comment: using basic javascript: let sumAge = 0;for(let i=0; i<student.length; i++) {sumAge += student[i].age;};let averageAge = sumAge / student.length;

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do it in JS actually:

```js
const students = [
  {name:"mia", age: 20},
  {name:"kia", age: 25},
  {name:"dia", age: 23}
];

const averageAge = students.reduce((sum, student) => sum + student.age, 0) / students.length;

console.log(averageAge)
```

Comment: how do i find average between 0 and 25

Comment: Well you apply the mathematical formula to compute the average. The above code snippet makes the average of the values of the "age" properties of each element on the "students" array.
i.e.: it does (20+25+23) / 3

Comment: yeah i understand that in mathematical formula, but how do i write that in js code?

Comment: Ok, so if you take the code that I wrote above it does the following. First, it declares an array of student objects, each with two properties, a name (which is a string) and an age (which is a number). Then, with the students.reduce, it takes all students, one by one, and sums their age, starting from 0. Then it divides that sum by the number of students. That is the textbook definition of the mathematical formula